# Playing local video on electron is too slow

Tags: electron

I'm using an electron to create a program that acts as a file explorer.
And if i click on a video file (not double click), i can play the video as a preview.
However, this work is too slow in Electron. A slight lag and delay continue to occur during playback, giving me the feeling that the program has stopped.
Loading local images is similarly slow,too.

Is this the limit of electron?
Or is there another good way?

```
//main
protocol.registerFileProtocol('video', async (request, callback) => {
    callback({ path: request.url.replace('video://', '') })
})
```

```
//renderer
<video autoplay>
    <source src="video://{path}" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by turning off hardware acceleration

```
app.disableHardwareAcceleration()
```